# Frame of View is not correct when scrolling in the scrollview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, size-classes

I implemented a scrollview with pagecontrol. I have some XIBs with SizeClass (wAny,hAny). When adding view of each Viewcontroller, the width is 600*600 but when change page, the width is 320*568  for iphone 5. Can you please help me to correct it? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
#define CONTENT_VIEW_HEIGHT     495
#define CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING    0
#define SCROLL_VIEW_PADDING     0

#define FIRST_PAGE              0
#define LAST_PAGE               self.numberOfPages - 1


@interface MLKPageViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *contentVCs;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger numberOfPages;
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL pageControlUsed;

@end

@implementation MLKPageViewController

@synthesize contentVCs;
@synthesize numberOfPages;
@synthesize pageControlUsed;

- (id)initWithContentViewControllers:(NSArray *)aContentVCs
{
    if( self = [super initWithNibName:@"PageViewVC" bundle:nil] )
    {
        self.contentVCs = aContentVCs;
        self.numberOfPages = aContentVCs.count;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Life Cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mlkPageControl.numberOfPages = self.numberOfPages;
    mlkPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self setupContentViews];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if( !pageControlUsed )
    {
        CGFloat pageWidth = contentScrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((contentScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2 ) / pageWidth) + 1;
        mlkPageControl.currentPage = page;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    pageControlUsed = NO;
    [self changeContentPage:mlkPageControl];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Methods

- (void)setupContentViews
{
    contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(( self.numberOfPages * ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 2 * SCROLL_VIEW_PADDING) ) + ( self.numberOfPages + 1 ) * CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING, CONTENT_VIEW_HEIGHT) ;

    for( int i = 0; i < self.numberOfPages; i++ )
    {
        UIView *contentView = ((UIViewController *)[self.contentVCs objectAtIndex:i]).view;
        contentView.frame = CGRectMake( ((i+1) * CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING) + i * contentView.frame.size.width, SCROLL_VIEW_PADDING, contentView.frame.size.width, contentView.frame.size.height);

        [contentScrollView addSubview:contentView];
    }
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark Actions

- (IBAction)changeContentPage:(id)sender
{
    CGRect pageRect;
    UIView *contentView = ((UIViewController *)[self.contentVCs objectAtIndex:mlkPageControl.currentPage]).view;
    NSInteger currentPage = mlkPageControl.currentPage;

    if( mlkPageControl.currentPage == FIRST_PAGE || mlkPageControl.currentPage == LAST_PAGE )
    {
        pageRect = CGRectMake( (currentPage * CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING) + currentPage *  contentView.frame.size.width, contentScrollView.frame.origin.y , contentScrollView.frame.size.width, contentScrollView.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        pageRect = CGRectMake( (currentPage * CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING) + currentPage *  contentView.frame.size.width - CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING, contentScrollView.frame.origin.y , contentScrollView.frame.size.width, contentScrollView.frame.size.height);
    }

    [contentScrollView scrollRectToVisible:pageRect animated:YES];
}
```

When the function `- (IBAction)changeContentPage:(id)sender` is called, the size is 320*568 but when calling `- (void)setupContentViews`, the size is 600*600.

Comment: Where is you size classes?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman: I size class for every sub viewcontroller (.xib) that added into the scrollview.

Comment: if you want the size to 600x600 then you have to remove the size class from that view controller because when you create a controller the size class will be applied according to the device dimension and it will resize it to that height and width.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman: If remove size class, when running on iphone 6 or 6 plus, the control will not de displayed correctly.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot from 5 and 6 device.

Comment: Are you reimplementing `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: @Andy: No, i used UIScrollVIew and UIpagecontrol

Comment: @NTNT which is what `UIPageViewController` is. :-)